# How do I call a method without a request from views in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, request, qr-code, laravel-7

I've had this question for a long time but i didn't know how to word it.

So for instance, I've had QRcode thumbnail in `/images/thumbnail/{{ Session::get('imageName') }}"` , and i need to Decode it with the Khanaamiryan library.
I've put these code in a method in the `DecodeController.php`.

```
$qrcode = new QrReader('/images/thumbnail/imageName.jpg');
$text = $qrcode->text();
```

now it's only a Method. without a request or an input from the view.blade.php whatsoever, the data that i require were on the local files. How do I call a method without a request/input?

What I've imagine is every time I reload the view.blade.php, the method get a call, and the $text echo'd on the screen.

Comment: Do you want to it run everytime you reload on all page or specific page ?

Comment: On a one specific page

Comment: You can run it from your `index` method in your `controller` (page controller)